# Union probably not right for this

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, union

I have a table witrh 3 columns:

```
id price created_at  
1    0      ts  
2    5      ts  
3    0      ts  
4    3      ts
```

I'd like to have a result table that contains 2 rows, like this:

```
id timestamp  
4  ts  
2  ts
```

To get the two rows above, I am using two queries.
Here is how I am currently selecting the first row:

```
select id, to_timestamp(created_at)::timestamp as timestamp
from (select * from web.orders where total > 0) as q 
order by id desc limit 1
```

Here is how I am selecting the second:

```
select id, to_timestamp(created_at)::timestamp as timestamp
from (select * from web.orders where total = 0) as q 
order by id desc limit 1
```

I tried to create the desired result table with UNION ALL of the above queries but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Did you receive an error message?  "Not working" could mean anything - you got more records than you expected, or fewer, or the wrong ones, or the computer exploded.  A replicable example would be perfect.

Comment: The queries you show don't match the data you've provided. Please clarify and correct your sample data and queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understood, this should give the desired result:

```
create table weborders (id int, total int , ts timestamp);
insert into weborders values
(1, 0, '20200101'),
(2, 5, '20200102'),
(3, 0, '20200103'),
(4, 3, '20200104');

with ct as
(
  select   0 as row_no, id, ts
  from     weborders
  where    total > 0
  order by id desc limit 1
)
, ct2 as
(
  select   1 as row_no, id, ts
  from     weborders
  where    total = 0
  order by id desc limit 1
)
select id, ts
from
(
  select row_no, id, ts from ct
  union
  select row_no, id, ts from ct2
) a
order by row_no;
```

or alternatively:

```
select id, ts
from
(
 select 0 as row_no, id, ts
 from   weborders
 where id = (select max(id) from weborders where total > 0)
 union
 select 1 as row_no, id, ts
 from   weborders
 where id = (select max(id) from weborders where total = 0)
) a
order by row_no;
```

> ```
> id | ts                 
> -: | :------------------
>  4 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00
>  3 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=79d451387b7a63a61f639623e069484a)*

And another smart solution, thanks to [@ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) for this.

```
select distinct on (total > 0)
         id, ts
from     weborders
order by (total > 0), id desc ;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=06d540d3f09a1fd370d138f1f6c5b58b)*

Comment: Thank you this is so simple, I just don't know how I missed this solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

do use window functions.

```
select id, ts, total
from (select
        id, 
        ts, 
        total,  
        rank() over (partition by total = 0 order by id desc) as rnk
      from weborders) as t
where rnk = 1
order by total desc
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c3cb66c43075f62e2fb2e55823ffc8d)

Comment: I really like your shorter solution, thank you!